# How to automatically find sequence of linear transformations

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

I have a set of three polynomials in `x` and `y`, and 9 real coefficients `a1`, `b1`, ... `c3`:

```
poly = {a1 x + b1 y + c1, a2 x + b2 y + c2, a3 x + b3 y + c3}
```

Is there a built-in Mathematica function that can *automatically* find a linear transformation (scalings and shifts only) that transformations the polynomials to the form:

```
poly = {d1 x, d2 y, d3 (x+y)+d4}
```

where `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4` are real numbers *independent* of `x` and `y`.  I'm having a lot of trouble with this since using `Solve` keeps resulting in `d4` depending on `x` and `y`.

I only need to find *one* solution to this problem.  The reason I would like to automate the solution is because sometimes certain coefficients may be zero (such as `a3=0` and `b2=0` etc...).

Answer (score 1):

These commands do not produce what you want since you said that `a3` or `b2` can be zero. Still they might be a good alternative of what you have done...

```
mStart = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}};
mStart.{x, y, 1}   
(* {c1 + a1 x + b1 y, c2 + a2 x + b2 y, c3 + a3 x + b3 y} *)

mEnd = {{d1, 0, 0}, {0, d2, 0}, {d3, d3, d4}};
mEnd.{x, y, 1}  
(* {d1 x, d2 y, d4 + d3 x + d3 y} *)

ClearAll[v]
vMat = Array[v, {3, 3}];
eqs = Thread[Flatten[mStart*vMat] == Flatten[mEnd]];
sol = Solve[eqs, Flatten[vMat], Reals]

(* {{v[1, 1] -> d1/a1, v[1, 2] -> 0, v[1, 3] -> 0, v[2, 1] -> 0, 
  v[2, 2] -> d2/b2, v[2, 3] -> 0, v[3, 1] -> d3/a3, v[3, 2] -> d3/b3, 
  v[3, 3] -> d4/c3}} *)

MatrixForm[vMat /. First[sol]]
```

[image]

```
((mStart*vMat) /. First[sol]).{x, y, 1}

(* {d1 x, d2 y, d4 + d3 x + d3 y} *)
```